# How to create java POJO for XML String for sting array?

Tags: android, xml

I am using the following code to achieve above mentioned but its not working. Please Guide.

```
class ItemAttributes {
     @Element(name = "Binding")
     private String binding;
     @Element(name = "Brand")
     private String brand;
     @Element(name = "Color")
     private String color;
     @Element(name = "EAN")
     private String ean;
     @Element(name = "EANList")
     private EANList eanLists;
     @Element(name = "Feature")
     private List<String> feature;
 }
```

Error:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Cannot
>   instantiate interface java.util.List for field 'feature' private
>   java.util.List ItemAttributes.feature

My XML Log Response in Retrofit:

```
"ItemAttributes": {
                    "Binding": "",
                    "Brand": "",
                    "Color": "",
                    "EAN": "",
                    "EANList": {
                        "EANListElement": ""
                    },
                    "Feature": ["","",""]
}
```

Comment: is the response json?

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter refer to this link.

Comment: my response is xml format

Comment: and i tried above link also but not able to create pojo for xml array string.

Comment: <ItemAttributes>
                <Binding>Electronics</Binding>
                <Brand>Motorola</Brand>
                <Color>Black</Color>
                <EAN></EAN>
                <EANList>
                    <EANListElement></EANListElement>
                </EANList>
                <Feature>8MP primary camera with dual LED flash and 5MP front facing camera with 1080p HD video (30 fps)</Feature>
               

                <Feature></Feature>
                <Feature></Feature>

Comment: these are the xml format response

Comment: If `feature` is a list, wouldn't you use the `@ElementList` annotation?

Comment: it is not element list , it's string array . i got the solution . @ElementListUnion({

            @ElementList(entry = "Feature", type = String.class, inline = true)
    })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just came across this looking for the answer myself.  The solution (in my case at least) was to define a concrete type that could be instantiated, rather than an abstract type.

```
@ElementList(name = "Feature")
private ArrayList<String> feature;
```

instead of

```
 @Element(name = "Feature")
 private List<String> feature;
```